# Transition between casing and baseboard?

Tags: door-frame

[image]

Transition between casing and baseboard. How to do a nice transition. Just use blocks? 
The upper side will be mittered.

Answer (score 2):

At least where I work, it's typical to run the casing to the floor and butt the base into the casing. If you're replacing casing, I'd go that way.

If you don't want to change the casing, then yes, blocks are the only reasonably elegant solution I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

If the opening has drywall now, add a jamb to cover the drywall on the inside of the opening after the base is cut and removed. Then mark where the door trim intersects with the base and cut that off too. When marking the base, hold the trim back from the edge of the jamb 1/4" to create a "reveal". That gives a better look than trying to hold it flush with the edge of the jamb.

This is the typical way that cased openings were trimmed before cost cutting in home construction came up with drywall wrapped openings.